# Why does this code only runs properly in only the python shell

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

It works fine on the shell but not in the IDE

New Contributor ;)
Also explain the reason

Thank you :)

**Edit**

IDE - PyCharm

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. Particular problem with your question is that "works fine" or its opposite are nothing one can really work with. Also, what IDE would be interesting.

Comment: Hii, thank you for your suggestion! I have added the IDE Name and Will surely try to implement other points in my next Question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always need to call a `mainloop()` at the end of the script

**Why does that code works perfectly fine in the Python Shell?**

Generally Speaking, The `Python Shell` interprets only one line at a time and once you call the `mainloop()` you won't be able to do anything with your `tkinter` window so in `python shell` it would be very inconvenient if you really think about it.

**Your Updated Code**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to point out that `TkObject.mainloop()` also needs to be at the ***end of the script***